# Searching through logs Unix

Tags: unix, search

Hi I'm searching through a very large log file for an error associated to an object that we'll just call `string` for now. I'm browsing the file in `less`, and searching for the string as `/string`. How can I get to the last result of `string` rather than starting at the first one? When I run `?string`I get

> pattern not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>G</kbd> to jump to the end of the file with `less`, then use <kbd>?</kbd>`searchstring` to search backward.

Or use

```
grep searchstring FILE | tail -n X
```

to find the last `X` matching line(s).